# Visual Studio/ASP.NET MVC Project Organization & Structure Links, Examples and Personal Preferences

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, project-structuring

I'm looking for multiple inputs on great project organization/structure, preferably especially for complex ASP.NET MVC projects (which will definitely go beyond the couple of folders initially created by the project type).

Project organization also includes topics like naming conventions, lumper/splitter preference on classes, number of actual projects vs. folder structure, one way vs. two way dependencies and so forth. My ultimate goal is to merge these ideas into something I personally consider good for my current complex ASP.NET MVC application and to learn from how others have structured their projects successfully. So if you have good links, pointers to relevant forum/blog entries/articles or personal preferences (maybe on a specific part? E.g. maybe you have a set number of projects which you always use as a base framework?), please let me learn from it!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with Billy McCafferty's S#arp Architecture project and go forward from there.

http://code.google.com/p/sharp-architecture/